# The mean and variance of a random variable X are 8 and 2 respectively. Let $g(x)=2x^2 −10x−50$. How to find the expectation of g(x)?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I understand that I first have to use the formula for variance to then get the equation $\mathbb{E}[g(X)^2] = 66$.

From here, how do I find the expected value for $g(x)$ given the expected value for $g^2(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\mathbb{E}[2X^2-10X-50]$$
$$=2\mathbb{E}[X^2]-10\mathbb{E}[X]-50$$

Note that
$$\text{var}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X] \implies \mathbb{E}[X^2]=\text{var}[X]+\mathbb{E}^2[X].$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see what you've done to split the expectation, but given that I only have the information E(x^2) = 66, how can I find E[g(x)] with the unknown variable E(x)?

Comment: @FlyingSquid The question states that mean of $X$ is $8$ ($\mathbb{E}[X]=8$) and variance of $X$ is $2$ ($\text{var}[X]=2$).

Comment: Omg sorry my brain isn't working.